# Multihread for requestmapping in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, selenium

So my application (spring-boot) runs really slow as it uses Selenium to scrape data, processes it and displays in the home page. I came across multithreading and I think it can be useful to my application to allow it to run faster, however the tutorials seem to display in the setting of a normal java application with a main. I wish to run each line of code in the method at the same time, how can I do that?

The methods get.. are all selenium methods. I'm looking to run these 4 lines of code simultaneously

```
   @Autowired
        private WebScrape webscrape;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String printTable(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("alldata", webscrape.getAllData());
        model.addAttribute("worldCases", webscrape.getWorlValues().get(0));
        model.addAttribute("worldDeaths", webscrape.getWorlValues().get(1));
        model.addAttribute("worldPop", webscrape.getWorlValues().get(2));

        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multithread Spring-boot controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944457/multithread-spring-boot-controller-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create threads and wait until they finish.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String printTable(ModelMap model) {
    // Create a thread and define his operation.
    Thread alldata = new Thread(() -> {
        model.addAttribute("alldata", webscrape.getAllData());
    });
    alldata.start(); // <-- This executes the thread without locking current code.

    // Create a thread and define his operation.
    Thread worldCases = new Thread(() -> {
        model.addAttribute("worldCases", webscrape.getWorlValues().get(0));
    });
    worldCases.start(); // <-- This executes the thread without locking current code.

    // Create a thread and define his operation.
    Thread worldDeaths = new Thread(() -> {
        model.addAttribute("worldDeaths", webscrape.getWorlValues().get(1));
    });
    worldDeaths.start(); // <-- This executes the thread without locking current code.

    // Create a thread and define his operation.
    Thread worldPop = new Thread(() -> {
        model.addAttribute("worldPop", webscrape.getWorlValues().get(2));
    });
    worldPop.start(); // <-- This executes the thread without locking current code.

    // Wait until every thread has finished.
    alldata.join();
    worldCases.join();
    worldDeaths.join();
    worldPop.join();

    return "index";
}
```

You have to take care of the thread-safety of the `ModelMap` variable. They will be acceder from different threads, adding attributes, etc. That means that it can fall on async exceptions if they are not prepared to.

Also, be careful with the number of threads your rest controller creates. As a suggestion, you can delegate this task to some other component that can manage threads better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked perfectly! I've got a few questions and I hope you don't mind answering them. 1) Async. So only worldCases is somewhat related to the others where it calls worldPop in it's method. Would you consider that async and thread-safe? 2) What's wrong if I more threads say 100? Does the issue only lies with my computer's hardware? If so, assuming the hardware is weak, are you suggesting to set the threads in batches?

Comment: @Fenzox about the number of threads, you can use some type of pool to control the maximum number of simultaneously threads. For example the Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Comment: And it's due to the limitations of the hardware right?

Comment: @Fenzox about the async problem, when you open different threads, they can try to access some data at the same time. Imagine that you have an Integer with value `1` and two threads are trying to update the value with a `+2` what will be the result? That's a problem! You have to manage thread looks/waits or use prepared classes like `AtomicInteger`/`ConcurrentHashMap` to avoid trying to update data by two threads at the same time.

Comment: @Fenzox it can be limited by hardware, yes, but the cause of the problem can be for different reasons, like for example someone calling your API too many times with bad intentions.

Comment: Regarding the hardware, say is spam, would you reccomend setting the limitations to the API elsewhere and not at the thread. Set up a gateway before everything else to check the IP/frequency etc elsewhere.  Or would you go with your original reccomendation

Comment: @Fenzox you should control the number of threads you can open to avoid overloading the machine. Having for example 20 workers, and using them as queue processors. That will make your method run fast when lower demand and a bit slower during higher amounts of traffic.

If you don't control that, your API can fall unavailable due to trying to answer everyone at the maximum speed.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Regarding the async. Saying I have int a = 1, int a gets used in thread1 which makes it 3. Thread 2 uses int a too and it calls the get method of int a. This is going to be a problem right? Then AtomicInteger/ConcurrentHashMap comes into picture